# how to apply inverse optical flow vector on an image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, vector, computer-vision, opticalflow

I have a small project on Moving object detection in moving camera in which i have to use negative optical flow vector to minimize ego motion compensation. I have a video and some particular consecutive frames in which average of negative optical flow vector has to be computed. I have already calculated Optical flow between say, (k-1)th and kth frame. Also, I have calculated average of optical flow vector V=[u,v], where v is the average of horizontal optical flow and u is the average of vertical flow. Now, I have to apply inverse of optical flow vector i.e., -V to the (k-1)th frame. I'm new to matlab and i don't know much about it. Please help

I have tried this code segment to do so but the results aren't as expected

`function I1=reverseOF(I,V)
R=I(:,:,1);
G=I(:,:,2);
B=I(:,:,3);
[m,n]=size(rgb2gray(I));
for i=1:m
    for j=1:n
    v1=[j i];
    v2=-V;
    v3=v1.*v2;
     R(floor(1+abs(v3(1,2))),floor(1+abs(v3(1,2))))=R(i,j);
     G(floor(1+abs(v3(1,2))),floor(1+abs(v3(1,2))))=G(i,j);
     B(floor(1+abs(v3(1,2))),floor(1+abs(v3(1,2))))=B(i,j);
     I1(floor(1+abs(v3(1,2))),floor(1+abs(v3(1,2))))=I(i,j);
    end 
end
 I1=cat(3,R,G,B);

enter code here`

I have used abs() function because otherwise some error was occuring like "attempted to access negative location; index must be a positive or logical".

Image A and Image B are the images that i have used to estimate the optical flow.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrGvY.jpg)

This is the result that i am obtaining after applying the above function.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjHXq.jpg)

Comment: can you elaborate more when you say "not as expected"? Can you add pictures? It is not clear what do you mean by "inverse". In fact you are doing calculating "opposite"...

Comment: @giosans, I have updated the images above. And not as expected is that i need to reverse the effect of optical flow in the (k-1)th frame in order to minimize ego motion occurred by camera motion.

Comment: Sorry @Neeraj, I do not know what is ego motion, I do not know what is V (a matrix, a number ?!? ), I do not know what reverseOF function and why you need two for loops. Try to comment above any line of code and write in general mathematic terms instead of physical terms [like Optical Flow], which many people would not be familiar with.

Comment: @giosans, the above code is the body of a matlab function named reverseOF() that i have created manually in matlab. V is the optical flow vector that i have calculated. reverseOF() function takes two inputs i.e., I and V, where I is the (k-1)th frame which I have shown as Image A and V is the optical flow vector whose value for this particular case is V=[1.0864 -0.8677].  The two for loops are for changing every pixel's coordinate in image A according to the optical flow vector V.

Comment: Just saying: An optical flow consisting of a single vector is no optical flow **at all**.

Comment: @AnderBiguri , I have taken average of overall optical flow vectors obtained from particular points to minimize the effect in image A. That's why the vector contains single vector.

Comment: @NeerajKumar that defeats a bit the purpose of optical flow, you could get a similar result with image registration faster and easier I believe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cant do this easily. This is a quite advanced research problem, because obtaining the inverse of a vector field on a mesh grid is not an easy problem, actually its quite hard.

Notice that your vector field (optical flow) start in a mesh grid, but it doesnt end in a mesh grid, it ends in random subpixel positions. If you just invert this field, doing `-V` is not enough! The result wont be the inverse!

This is a open research problem, look for example at [this 2010 paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2837727/) that addresses exactly this issue, and proposes a method to create "pseudoinverses".

Suppose you have that inverse, because you computed it somehow. Your code is quite bad for it, and the solutions (abs!) are showing (no offense) that you are not really understanding what you are doing. For a known vector field `{Vx,Vy}`, size equals to the image size (if its not, you can figure out easily how to interpolate it unsig `interp2` ) the code would look something like:

```
newimg=zeros(size(I));

[ix,iy]=meshgrid(1:size(I,1),1:size(I,2));

newimg(:,:,1)=interp2(I(:,:,1),ix+Vx,iy+Vy); % this is your whole loop.
newimg(:,:,2)=interp2(I(:,:,3),ix+Vx,iy+Vy); % this is your whole loop.
newimg(:,:,3)=interp2(I(:,:,2),ix+Vx,iy+Vy); % this is your whole loop.
```